# How do I find the SourceLocation of the commas between function arguments using libtooling?

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

My main goal is trying to get macros (or even just the text) before function parameters. For example:

`void Foo(_In_ void* p, _Out_ int* x, _Out_cap_(2) int* y);`

I need to gracefully handle things like macros that declare parameters (by ignoring them).

`#define Example _In_ int x
void Foo(Example);`

I've looked at Preprocessor record objects and used Lexer::getSourceText to get the macro names *In*, *Out*, etc, but I don't see a clean way to map them back to the function parameters.

My current solution is to record all the macro expansions in the file and then compare their SourceLocation to the ParamVarDecl SourceLocation. This mostly works except I don't know how to skip over things after the parameter.

`void Foo(_In_ void* p _Other_, _In_ int y);`

Getting the SourceLocation of the comma would work, but I can't find that anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of the questions asks for `libclang`, but as you use `Lexer::getSourceText` I assume that it's `libTooling`. The rest of my answer is viable only in terms of `libTooling`.

### Solution 1

Lexer works on the level of tokens. *Comma* is also a token, so you can take the end location of a parameter and fetch the next token using [Lexer::findNextToken](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Lexer.html#a346f4578b2601708a54f60a7746016e6).

Here is a `ParmVarDecl` (for function parameters) and `CallExpr` (for function arguments) visit functions that show how to use it:

```cpp
template <class T> void printNextTokenLocation(T *Node) {
  auto NodeEndLocation = Node->getSourceRange().getEnd();

  auto &SM = Context->getSourceManager();
  auto &LO = Context->getLangOpts();

  auto NextToken = Lexer::findNextToken(NodeEndLocation, SM, LO);
  if (!NextToken) {
    return;
  }
  auto NextTokenLocation = NextToken->getLocation();

  llvm::errs() << NextTokenLocation.printToString(SM) << "\n";
}

bool VisitParmVarDecl(ParmVarDecl *Param) {
  printNextTokenLocation(Param);
  return true;
}

bool VisitCallExpr(CallExpr *Call) {
  for (auto *Arg : Call->arguments()) {
    printNextTokenLocation(Arg);
  }
  return true;
}
```

For the following code snippet:

```cpp
#define FOO(x) int x
#define BAR float d
#define MINUS -
#define BLANK

void foo(int a, double b     ,
         FOO(c)   , BAR) {}

int main() {
  foo(   42     ,
      36.6 ,   MINUS 10    ,   BLANK 0.0  );
  return 0;
}
```

it produces the following output (six locations for commas and two for parentheses):

```
test.cpp:6:15
test.cpp:6:30
test.cpp:7:19
test.cpp:7:24
test.cpp:10:17
test.cpp:11:12
test.cpp:11:28
test.cpp:11:43
```

This is quite a low-level and error-prone approach though. However, you can change the way you solve the original problem.

### Solution 2

Clang stores information about expanded macros in its source locations. You can find related methods in `SourceManager` (for example, [isMacroArgExpansion](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#a66eb9cc00c37e0958be7b2bb1bb74278) or [isMacroBodyExpansion](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#a04eadd011628b7c4cd3304712c8c221c)). As the result, you can visit `ParmVarDecl` nodes and check their locations for macro expansions.

I would strongly advice moving in the second direction.

I hope this information will be helpful. Happy hacking with Clang!

**UPD** speaking of attributes, unfortunately, you won't have a lot of choices. Clang does ignore *any* unknown attribute and this behaviour *is not tweakable*. If you don't want to patch Clang itself and add your attributes to [Attrs.td](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/Basic/Attr.td), then you're limited indeed to tokens and the first approach.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I updated the title. I had tried findNextToken as well, but no luck - it always returned null. What I really want is custom attributes (C++11 attributes or even __declspec/__attribute) to persist into the AST. It's very strange that clang drops them.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, although as suggested, I agree it is error prone. I am going to look into using __attribute__(annotate) instead so they aren't dropped.